# Resource locking in embedded tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

How can I set `antiResourceLocking="true"` for embedded tomcat 8?

I don't find any method for this.

I use embedded tomcat 8.5.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your `org.apache.catalina.Context` object to `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext` and then call `StandardContext#setAntiResourceLocking(true)`.